# Dismiss ProgressDialog after WebView loads url does not work

Tags: android, url, webview, dialog, progressdialog

I created a webview and while the page is loading, there will be a ProgressDialog. Well, until this point all works. 
But now I want that the ProgressDialog is dismiss after loading the url. 
This doesn't work.

My Code:

```
private WebView webViewNews;
private ProgressDialog progressDialogWebViewNews;

  webViewNews = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewNews);
  WebSettings webSettings = webViewNews.getSettings();
  webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  webViewNews.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
      @Override
      public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
          super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
          progressDialogWebViewNews = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
          progressDialogWebViewNews.setCancelable(false);
          progressDialogWebViewNews.setTitle("Demo...");
          progressDialogWebViewNews.setMessage("Demo");
          progressDialogWebViewNews.show();
      }

      @Override
      public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
          progressDialogWebViewNews.dismiss();
          super.onPageFinished(view, url);
      }
  });
  webViewNews.loadUrl("http://www.demo.com");
```

Comment: Try using `setVisibility` method along this to set the visibility to `GONE`

Comment: @NoLuckPulak very interesting workaround but that is extremely bad design. will lead to memory leaks.

Comment: Ya you are right @SoroushA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a variable to an anonymous class, the variable automatically becomes final which stops it from changing. Try having the progress dialog as a member of the inner client class instead. This also is a better design and makes your code more maintainable.

```
class MyClient extends WebViewClient() {
      private ProgressDialog progressDialogWebViewNews;

      public MyClient(Context c){
             progressDialogWebViewNews = new ProgressDialog(c);
      }

      @Override
      public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
          super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
          progressDialogWebViewNews.setCancelable(false);
          progressDialogWebViewNews.setTitle("Demo...");
          progressDialogWebViewNews.setMessage("Demo");
          progressDialogWebViewNews.show();
      }

      @Override
      public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
          progressDialogWebViewNews.dismiss();
          super.onPageFinished(view, url);
      }
}

webViewNews.setWebViewClient(new MyClient(MainActivity.this));
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete `super.onPageFinished(view, url)`,Then first check if progress dialog is showing before you dismiss it in your callback method.

```
If (progressDialogWebViewNews.showing){
progressDialogWebViewNews.dismiss();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should create a simple WebView object:

```
    WebView webView = (WebView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("yourURL");
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    progressDialog.show();
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

It works for me.

Comment: Sorry, but the problem continues.

Comment: `setCancelable` is for user interaction. has nothing to do with `dismiss`

Comment: @SoroushA I know, in fact it's strange